# Finding the maximum number of cores available for processing

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I had instantiated a session with a known number of cores. Once the session starts one can utilize how many ever number required. For example, if I instantiated the session with 12 cores I can ask for 8 of those using the following command:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(8)
```

Is there a command in Julia 1.1.0 to know the number `12`, that is the maximum number of available cores?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu. The command should be issuable through Julia

Comment: Have a look here... https://askubuntu.com/a/724236

Comment: That's a way, but I am looking for getting that info through Julia

Comment: Something like `run('grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo')` where the quotes are backticks though... http://blog.leahhanson.us/post/julia/julia-commands.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of logical cores is given in `Sys.CPU_THREADS`.

Comment: On the server that I have access to, I can access a maximum of `x` number of cores. But, I have requested for `y` (`y` < `x`) cores. When I issue the command `Sys.CPU_THREADS` I get `x` when what I expect to get is `y`. So, I'm looking for a magical command that gives me this `y` :-). Let me know if I could be a bit more helpful with my question, thank you!

Comment: @SchlatorBorgenson so you want to know `8` not `12` in your code unlike what you described in your question?

Comment: maybe https://github.com/m-j-w/CpuId.jl or https://github.com/JuliaParallel/Hwloc.jl will suit your needs? Or you are simply looking for `nprocs` and `nworker` functions?

Comment: When I give Sys.CPU_THREADS I get a number like 60 (which is the total number of cores available on the node). I started a session with the request to allocate 12 cores, and I can choose to use 8 cores by issuing the command addprocs(8). Before issuing addprocs(8), nworkers() returns 1 and after issuing addprocs(8), it returns 8. But, I couldn't find a function that returns 12, which is the number I started the session with.